# Batch process macro in Fiji fails to work

Tags: image-processing, imagej, fiji

I have a hyperstack which has 2 time frames and 13 z projection in each time frame. From the menu I choose `Process`, `Batch`, and then `Macro`. In the `input` I select the input folder and then determine the output folder in the `output`. Finally I use the code below to sum all the z projection:

```
run("Z Project...", "projection=[Max Intensity] all");
close();
```

Here is an screenshot:

[image]

After running `process` or `Test` the file I get in the output is the same as input without the z projection being summed.
[Here is a sample](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=13296442674091299854) `tif` file (13 MB). I tried to do this on different computers but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with using batch process in this way, so I'm not sure I can address your issue directly, but, I can say that I know how to do this by recording/writing a macro directly. First though, have you tried using the "Save" button provided in the GUI you screenshotted? In that case, if it still doesn't work, you'd maybe want to do something like this in the macro editor instead:

```
openPath = getDirectory("Choose Source Directory");

savePath = getDirectory("Choose Save Location");
File.makeDirectory(savePath + "UNIQUE ID");
savePath = savePath + "UNIQUE ID" + File.separator;

files = getFileList(openPath);

setBatchMode(true);
for (timePoint = 0; timePoint < (files.length); timePoint++)
    {
        run("Z Project...", "projection=[Max Intensity] all");
        saveAs("Tiff", savePath + "UNIQUE ID");
        close();
    }
setBatchMode(false);
```

I hope that helps some!

Comment: Is this meant to fully work? I am getting error: ```There are no images open in line 12
run("Z Project...", "projection=[Max Intensity] all<)>;```

Comment: It has been a long time since I’ve thought about this, but you can look over the code in this repo (https://github.com/evankiely/FIJIMacros) for more insight. It’s well commented and I’d been using it actively in a lab environment, so it has been validated, and should still work, as long as there have been no breaking changes made to FIJI/IJM2 since then. I will say, in reviewing the code again, that it is likely for loop is just iterating over the length of number of files without ever opening them. If you can’t find a solution in the repo I linked to, let me know and I’ll look more deeply